# Passing the Phone Number data through Internal SMS API?

Tags: php, api, sms

I am working on a project where I have a table data with Name,city,age,Phone Numbers and we have an Internal SMS API URL where the Phone numbers data which I have got has to send an SMS message by triggering the API URL by using POST method.

Let's Say I have 100 phone numbers in my table and the SMS has to be send to those 100 numbers one by one by using that API.

I have searched lot of articles but couldn't find my solution. So can anyone Kindly suggest how can I achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

=> Get all **Phone Numbers** from db check [Example](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp).

=> Iterate all records using `while` loop .

=> Set all **Phone Numbers** to your API.